# no NDK arm-linux-androideabi-gcc on $PATH at (eval 13)

Tags: android, openssl, android-ndk

To use `openssl` on Android, install NDK and set environment variables.
Since I use a Mac, I enter the environment variables in `~/.zshrc`.

**1. openssl install**

```
git clone https://github.com/openssl/openssl
```

**2. zshrc file**

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/flutter/bin"
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform_tools
export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle
export ANDROID_COMPILER=$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin
export CC=$ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN/armv7a-linux-androideabi21-clang
export PATH=$(echo $PATH | tr -s ':' '\n' | awk '!seen[$0]++' | tr '\n' ':')
export PATH=${PATH%:}
```

**3. openssl build**

```
./Configure android-arm
```

An error occurs when you enter the above command.

```
no NDK arm-linux-androideabi-gcc on $PATH at (eval 13) line 143.
```

Is there a way to resolve the error and use it on Android by linking `openssl` with ndk normally?

Comment: Unclear if you are following: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/NOTES-ANDROID.md as you don't mention which version of NDK and API you are targeting.

Comment: ./Configure CC=clang android-arm